# Does TeamViewer's remote control transfer voice to the remote host?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, microphone, privacy

When I connect to my work computer with TeamViewer, the "microphone in use" icon appears in the Windows notification bar. I didn't change the default settings. The Windows 10 privacy settings show this:

[image: Windows 10 microphone privacy settings showing "Currently in use" label under TeamViewer.]

I find this upsetting privacy-wise. Does this mean that my voice is constantly recorded and sent to the remote computer?

Comment: You can disable microphone access to TeamViewer within TeamViewer itself.  TeamViewer by default wants access to support audio calls.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, I'd just like to be sure what the default is. If I I simply launch remote control, will the voice be transmitted, or not?

Comment: Yes; It’s enabled unless you disable it.

Comment: So to be sure: do you mean that *the microphone is only capturing* by default, or that *voice is broadcast on the remote computer* by default? My coworkers told me they hadn't heard anything from the remote computer even though my microphone was on and I was speaking (and the volume on the remote computer was on high), so I'm a bit confused by your answer.

Comment: It’s not an answer, is an observation, submitted at a comment since I don’t know your TeamViewer settings

Comment: Well I did say I hadn't changed the default settings. I don't understand what they entail though, there isn't any indicator of whether I'm currently broadcasting voice or not.